# Framework to read and write user settings in local storage in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage, settings

I want to store some (a lot) of user depended UI settings in my angular app. What is visible, what values are currently selected etc.
This settings should persist over time in the browser.

Thus, I created a SettingsService I can inject in every component to read and set the needed settings values - and receive update notifications for my property binding:

```
export class SettingsService {

   private message = new BehaviorSubject('');
   sharedMessage = this.message.asObservable();

   private propertiesChanged: EventEmitter<{ name: string, value: any }> = new EventEmitter();

   //First Property:
   public showPercentName = 'showpercent';
   private _showPercent: boolean;

   get showPercent(): boolean {
      return this._showPercent;
   }

   set showPercent(s: boolean) {
      this._showPercent = s;
      this.propertiesChanged.emit({ name: this.showPercentName, value: s });
   }

   // Second property:
   // ...

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      this.loadSettings();
      this.propertiesChanged.subscribe(x => this.changesDetected(x));
   }

   changesDetected(value) {
      this.writeAllSettings();
      this.message.next(value.name);
   }

   loadSettings() {

      //First Property
      let tempBool = localStorage.getItem(this.showPercentName);
      if (tempBool === undefined || tempBool === null || tempBool === 'true') {
         this.showPercent = true;
      }
      else {
         this.showPercent = false;
      }

      // Second Property
      // ...
   }


   writeAllSettings() {

      //First Property
      if (this.showPercent !== undefined) {
         localStorage.setItem(this.showPercentName, this.showPercent.toString());
      }

      //Second Property
      // ..
   }
}
```

And this SettingsService I can use in my components like:

```
constructor(private settings: SettingsService) {
}
```

... with property binding:

```
<my-comp [showPercent]="this.settings.showPercent"></my-comp>
```

This solutions works fine - but it is very annoying to write that much for every property you want to store in the local storage of the user.

Thus, my question is: **Is there a better, easier and more lightweight way to store, read and update via property binding different settings in Angular/TS?**
I searched a lot but did not found any obvious package or framework.

Comment: This might help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-pwa/local-storage

Comment: Please keep in mind that any user can delete local storage in the browser.

Comment: Sure, the user can delete all data and gets the default behavior of the app/webpage.